# Windows Task Scheduler Return Code 2147942511

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

I've defined something to run on Task Scheduler and I'm always getting the return code 2147942511 on the History log. It just gives me an empty log of the batch script I defined to be executed.

When I try to run the batch script manually, it works perfectly well.

Scheduled Task Info:
OS is Windows 2012 R2. I'm using an account with logon as batch job, task is set to execute with highest privileges, execute even user is not logged on, do not store password is ticked.

Comment: Not enough information to help. But you might have more success looking at the hex equivalent of that code: `0x8007006f`.

Comment: @markransom But my path together with the file name is just d:\abc_de\abc\batch\asdf-src2tgt-dly-run.bat. I find it strange that it throws a filename too long.

Answer (score 0):

2147942511 is 0x8007006f or ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW which according to MSDN has message "The file name is too long." Have you tried shortening the path of your batch script file?

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Hi. The current path is somewhat on this length (actual names masked) d:\abc_de\abc\batch\asdf-src2tgt-dly-run.bat. Let me try to run it in a shortened path